# AngularJS math gotcha in official guide

Tags: angularjs, math

I am starting with `AngularJS`, reading developer guide - conceptual overview.

I only got to the first example - simple calculator - and found a strange behaviour of AngularJS, namely following expression:

> {{qty * cost | currency}}

with small numbers it works, with large numbers it outputs exponential in result, but with some values in-between the result is, unexpectedly, `NaN`.

Same numbers in vanilla javascript do NOT return `NaN`, of course.

For example:

```
2222222222 and 200000000000
```

Can someone please explain this behaviour?

Comment: Suggest you create a demo that replicates these behaviors

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/s2cu4EzLBiBJ37cyxUs9?p=preview (link from official docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to figure these kinds of problems out is to try and recreate them. The console in your developer tools is perfect for this.

```
> 2222222222 * 200000000000
444444444400000000000
```

So, there's nothing strange here. Javascript can handle the multiplication. That means we can be sure that the weirdness is arriving from the currency filter.

Next stop is the source for the filter itself. If you visit the docs for an [Angular module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency), then there's a [view source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L3) button that will take you straight to the source file on GitHub.

The currency filter itself isn't too much code.

```
function currencyFilter($locale) {
  var formats = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS;
  return function(amount, currencySymbol, fractionSize) {
    if (isUndefined(currencySymbol)) {
      currencySymbol = formats.CURRENCY_SYM;
    }

    if (isUndefined(fractionSize)) {
      fractionSize = formats.PATTERNS[1].maxFrac;
    }

    // if null or undefined pass it through
    return (amount == null)
        ? amount
        : formatNumber(amount, formats.PATTERNS[1], formats.GROUP_SEP, formats.DECIMAL_SEP, fractionSize).
            replace(/\u00A4/g, currencySymbol);
  };
}
```

The only place the `amount` variable gets used is in the `formatNumber` call, along with a load of other stuff from `$locale.NUMBER_FORMATS`.

A quick check in [`src/ngLocale/angular-locale_en-us.js`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngLocale/angular-locale_en-us.js#L96) shows us the bits we care about.

```
formats.PATTERNS[1] = {
  "gSize": 3,
  "lgSize": 3,
  "maxFrac": 2,
  "minFrac": 2,
  "minInt": 1,
  "negPre": "-\u00a4",
  "negSuf": "",
  "posPre": "\u00a4",
  "posSuf": ""
}
```

The other arguments are just formatting details. Now lets take at this `formatNumber` method. It's pretty long, so I'll try and cut to the important bits.

Early on, our number is converted to a string [`var numStr = number + '',`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L152).

After this it becomes non-trivial to dry run the code by reading it, so head back to the demo and throw in a breakpoint at the start of the `formatNumber` function (Line 18580 in the non minified version of Angular).

If we step over functions, we can see the `numStr` assigned to `h` in our local scope. When we step to line 18627, the `h` local becomes `"NaN"`.

At 18617 I can see two variables `b` and `h` that seem to contain our value.

```
b = 444444444400000000000
h = "444444444400000000000"
```

And at 18619 `b` has become `NaN`. `h` remains unchanged. So the offending line of code is

```
number = +(Math.round(+(number.toString() + 'e' + fractionSize)).toString() + 'e' + -fractionSize);
```

Now we're getting somewhere. This code is littered with things that are going to be trying to coerce numbers to strings and vice versa.

`fractionSize` came in as the last argument to the function. Which as we know from before was the `maxFrac` field of our locale number formats pattern.

```
"maxFrac": 2,
```

Let's start substituting values in the function call, so that we can run it in our console.

```
var number = 444444444400000000000;
var fractionSize = 2;

+(Math.round(+(number.toString() + 'e' + fractionSize)).toString() + 'e' + -fractionSize);
```

We can use this to confirm that this does actually create `NaN`.

Now to break it down to find out why. The innermost expression is as follows

```
number.toString() + 'e' + fractionSize
// "444444444400000000000e2"
```

This value is coerced back to a number straight away with the `+` operator.

```
+(number.toString() + 'e' + fractionSize)
// 4.444444444e+22
```

Then this number is rounded, but it stays the same. Then it's converted back into a string.

```
Math.round(+(number.toString() + 'e' + fractionSize)).toString()
// "4.444444444e+22"
```

For the sake of being able to read this, lets call that value `x`.

```
x = "4.444444444e+22"
```

Now we concatenate `x` with another `'e'` and `-fractionSize`.

```
x + 'e' + -fractionSize
// "4.444444444e+22e-2"
```

We're starting to see where this went wrong. Finally, the `+` operator is used again to coerce the string into a number.

```
+(x + 'e' + -fractionSize)
// NaN
```

Bingo.

What happened? The implementation of the number rounding appears to have an edge case. Earlier on it checks to see whether the number contains an exponent, then deals with it accordingly if it does. However, as shown here there are some edge cases where large numbers end up with two exponents in this rounding method. Seeing as that's not valid notation, the number can't be coerced and ends up as NaN.

This edge case is almost certainly related to the fact that you picked numbers which when multiplied, exceeded the bounds of `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (9007199254740991). Generally speaking, when you are working with numbers this big, you can expect to find lots of code that won't handle them in the way you might expect. Especially if that code is going to be converting them backwards and forwards between strings and numbers.

Finally, that NaN value is converted back to a string and fed through to the currency filter.